# How do get the URL of my opened app?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

Another asp.net/c# app open my WPF app through a link with a query string.  When my WPF app opens or launch in a browser, how do I capture or get the URL?

Comment: Please be a bit more clear when asking a question. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: WPF? Are you doing this with ClickOnce?

Comment: Yes, I have a c# WPF using VS 2015 and Framwork 4.5.  I'm also using ClickOnce.  My WPF app, http://localhost/xpab_test/WPFHost.xbap open in a browser just fine without any issue.  I'm new to WPF and did not know how get the URL including the querystring in the URL from the browser. e.g. http://localhost/xpab_test/WPFHost.xbap?id=1

Comment: So you know for the future, ClickOnce is completely independent from WPF. So if you have any problems like this in the future, make sure that you search for "ClickOnce" rather than WPF.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx

```
private NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
{
    NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();

    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }

    return (nameValueTable);
}
```

Comment: Will give this a try, thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

With Jonathan Allen suggestion, My working code below which avoids using the System.Web reference for HttpUtility

```
private NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
    {
        NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();

        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
            string[] querySegments = queryString.Split('&');
            foreach (string segment in querySegments)
            {
                string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
                if (parts.Length > 0)
                {
                    string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
                    string val = parts[1].Trim();
                    //MessageBox.Show("key=" + key + " val=" + val);
                    nameValueTable.Add(key, val);
                }
            }

        }

        return (nameValueTable);
    }
```